# Image upload button unresponsive when failed URL upload

Tags: bug, uploader

When using the image upload/embed feature and using the "link from the web" feature with an URL that fails (see image below) the large "Drag and drop or click here" box does not respond to clicks until the "Close" link it clicked. Note that dragging an image does work, even when the "Failed to upload image; the format is not supported" error is displayed.

[image]